# Send OTP on email instead of SMS -Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, multi-factor-authentication

Is there a way to send OTP by email instead of SMS?
SMS's have a bunch of limitations and regulations in different countries and TOTP happens to be so not friendly to non-technical users.
I understand I can have custom flow but we would like to continue using Amplify for the login. What's the most straightforward way to achieve this in the cognito service?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an email solution out-of-box, but the setup is relatively straightforward using custom flow, lambda triggers and amazon SES. You can follow this tutorial on the AWS blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/extending-amazon-cognito-with-email-otp-for-2fa-using-amazon-ses/

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't be using the Amplify

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

##You can select preferred mfa type, for example:
##Select TOTP as preferred

```
Auth.setPreferredMFA(user, 'TOTP').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    // ...
}).catch(e => {});
```

// Select SMS as preferred

```
Auth.setPreferredMFA(user, 'SMS');
```

// Select no-mfa

```
Auth.setPreferredMFA(user, 'NOMFA');
```

Comment: Doesn't address the question.

Comment: I explain to you can't able achieve that.

Comment: It is possible. Please look up customSMSSender.